# Accessing virtual hosts from remote?

Tags: linux, remote-access

I have a Linux (debian7) and i run a lot of different virtual hosts (for all my projects) - apache2 ,and i usually use my development server to test new features via mobile devices (for mobile devices) ,but that takes to long.How can i set-up my config on my Linux so i can access the virtual host from my mobile device (on the same network - WiFi).

I've found several similar topic here on SO and else ware,but i had no success implementing them.(i am fairly new to Linux).

My standard `.conf` file looks like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
     ServerName lorem.ipsum
     ServerAlias lorem.ipsum
     DocumentRoot /home/user_name/Projects/lorem.ipsum/
     ErrorLog /home/user_name/Projects/errors_log/lorem.ipsum/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the mobile device does not know where to go if you write "lorem.ipsum" in its address bar, you need to add the ip and dns to the mobile device's host file.
for android you can use the app "Hosts Editor" from playstore for that purpose.

- IP: IP of your debian server
- HOST: lorem.ipsum

it should work then.

[add]
you can get the ip of your linux PC from the command line, just type

```
ifconfig
```

in console and look for the IP of (usually) eth0. something like 192.168.xxx.xxx should be ok.

Comment: I tried this.I added my ip adress into the Android Host file,but when i target the host,i get logged into my Router/Modem settings,like when i type on my pc the ip at the bottom of modem.

Comment: well, sounds like you took the wrong ip. edited answer. next guess would be, that your router does not route Wifi clients into LAN, assuming that your linux box is connected via LAN cable. then you should look into your router config for an option to allow connecting wifi and lan clients. but be careful, dont change too much.

Comment: Worked like a charm! :) ty so much Cari